# Hardcoded PHP Login

Tags: php, security, authentication, session, authorization

I am reviewing previous undocumented php work from a predecessor on these two scripts to manage access to an administrative dashboard, but I'm not sure about vulnerabilities and other things that usually go unnoticed.
I tried to improve on his design and this is the result.

Is this login check secure?

```
<?php
session_start();

$check1 = (empty($_SESSION) || $_SESSION['admin'] != true);
$check2 = ($_SESSION['NO_HIJACK'] == (
        ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?? '?') . '+' .
        ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? '?')));

if ($check1 || $check2) {
    http_response_code(401);
    header("Location: http://admin.example.com");
    exit(0);
}

?>
```

This is the verification script that receives the login key from the login form with a jquery post:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['key'])) {
    $controlKey = array();
    $controlKey[] = 'token1';
    $controlKey[] = 'token2';
    $controlKey[] = 'token3';
    $hKey = hash('sha256', $_POST['key']);
    if (in_array($hKey, $controlKey)) {
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['NO_HIJACK'] = (($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?? '?') .
            '+' . ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? '?'));
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "success"));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "fail"));
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "empty"));
}
?>
```

Comment: Firstly: this code is a big **NO**, its so prone to [session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking), its not even funny. For the password check itself: if you are not going to enable admins to change their passwords (by storing then in DB) in future (which would require rework of the whole code), then I would at least change `md5()` to `hash('sha256', key)`. Also, I don't understand why he used `base64_encode()`, it adds no additional security... If you go with passwords in DB, then take a look at `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions in PHP.

Comment: @insertusernamehere yes, that is an option, but you would have to go through an array and check every password, and `password_verify()` isn't that fast. But for administration (where optimizing every little thing usually doesn't matter that much), it is an viable option.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to fix these things and update my question. For base64 I guess he wanted to store the keys in the database. Also the key array maximum size won't exceed 10.

Comment: @beppe9000 but you do not need `base64_encode()` to store passwords in database... Again, it doesn't really do anything for you. And if somebody got to that password, he could just use `base64_decode()`. One thing with this implementation is, anybody can use any password. Are there different users, or just single user and admins themselves have different passwords for that single user? Ps.: With only 10 passwords max, I would use the `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for added security.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB Maybe he thought that the md5 function output was binary? Users have a separate login, that is required to access this one.

Comment: @beppe9000 Well the `md5()` returns 32 characters and `base64_encode()` returns 44 characters. Anyway, just don't use it :D And if users have separate logins with separate passwords, then change the array and assign every password to certain user like this: `$controlKey['root'] = 'password_hash';` that way you can check password like this `if (array_key_exists($userName, $controlKey) && password_verify($hKey, $controlKey[$userName])){ /* success */ }`. I probably should write this as an answer, but I am at work, so that answer would have more edits than some Wikipedia posts :D

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB It works more like this: user logs in, then he's allowed to operate the admin login form where he can login to site administration using a token (the user name is not needed as it is already in the session).

Comment: @beppe9000 you are doing something similar to me on one of my websites, but I am still checking the user name (from DB) against their password (and only theirs). With this code, *user123* can login using password from *user456* or *root* and that is **not** good.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect previous comments. I chose to keep the tokens hardcoded. @MiChAeLoKGB these tokens are not associated with a specific user, as there is another system in place for that. They are just here for elevated access control. I will add rate control in the future.

Comment: @beppe9000 If there is some mechanism that checks, if the password corresponds to logged user, then thats good. And as for the the edited code, I quite agree with answer from @tim With the small amount of passwords, you should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Security

First of all, the things you are doing right which are often missed: You die after a redirect (otherwise there wouldn't actually be any protection) and you regenerate the session id (which can prevent/mitigate session fixation).

**Hashing**

You shouldn't use sha256, as it's rather fast. Instead, use bcrypt (password_hash and password_verify).

**Session Highjacking**

Binding the session to the IP is a [controversial](https://github.com/OWASP/phpsec/issues/84) measure, as it can negatively effect usability. If it makes sense in the context of your application it's a good measure though.

Binding to the user agent does not have the same downside. But note that the user agent can relatively easily be bruteforced, so you should definitely terminate the session if a violation is found.

**General Approach**

About the general approach: I don't like the control key mechanism with multiple keys which are independent of user accounts, as it increases the probability that a key is bruteforced. On the other hand, I assume that you can't just use one shared key, as then you couldn't revoke admin privileges of just one user.

If this is about a sort of second password to elevate to special privileges, I would suggest a proper privilege management that is bound to specific user accounts (ie you have non-admin and admin users, which may have a secondary password to access more privileged actions).

**Hardcoded Credentials**

I'm not a fan of hardcoding credentials like this (it makes them difficult to change by a user, source code is more likely to be shared than database content, etc), but if you need to do it, try to store them in a specific config file which doesn't contain any other code (ideally outside of the web root). That way it's easier not to leak them in version control etc.

**Other**

Your code doesn't contain bruteforce protection or session expiration, but I'm assuming that that is handled somewhere else.

### Misc

- check1 and check2 aren't very good variable names. isAdmin and isHijacked would be better.
- if you reverse your first `if` (and maybe also the second one), it's easier to see what happens in what case.